# is a gen_server is up?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor, gen-server

Is there a way to tell a gen_server: "supervisor has initialised all gen_servers, now you can send then messages"?

I have a worker gen_server whose job is to set up states of other gen_servers in his supervision tree. If I just start sending messages in init function of my configuration server, sometimes it gets {noproc, _}. I suppose that means that config server was to fast: he sent messages before supervisor had enough time to start all workers. I fixed that by putting timer:sleep(500) in config_server:init(), which ensures all gen_server had enough time to initialise, but this seems like a inelegant solution.

Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return tuple with timeout `0` from `init`. Then immediately after it returns, `handle_info(timeout, State)` will be called. In `handle_info` make some call which won't return until the supervisor finishes initialization (e.g. `supervisor:which_children`).

Comment: Note: it's not possible to call `supervisor:which_children` in `init`, because before the supervisor knows a child was correctly initialized, the child calls `proc_lib:init_ack`. The timeout solution fixes this, but a `send_cast` also works.

Answer (score 0):

in function `init()` call `gen_server:cast(init, State)`. message "init" will be first in message queue

Answer (score 0):

```
info(PlayerId) ->
Pid = case global:whereis_name(util:getRegName({?MODULE, PlayerId})) of
    P when is_pid(P) ->
        P;
    _ ->
        {ok, P} = player_sup:start_child(PlayerId),
        P
end,
gen_server:call(Pid, info).
```

This is my case to handle this issue.  This worker process is triggered only when it is requested.